# LVL license check from Intent Service

Tags: android, android-lvl, intentservice

I have a free app which also contains pro functionality, which will be available to the user if they buy a pro key for my app in the Android Market. I have set up a receiver in the pro key app and another one in the main app. When the user clicks a "Validate key" button in the main app, an intent gets broadcasted to the receiver in the key app, which then fires up an IntentService to check if the pro key license is valid. Then the IntentService broadcasts an intent  to the main app receiver containing a "response" extra from the LVL check.

I'm almost there. Only when I tried to do the LVL check in the IntentService, I got an error:

```
W/MessageQueue(2652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{4052de20} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
W/MessageQueue(2773):   at com.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker$ResultListener.verifyLicense(LicenseChecker.java:207)
```

Any suggestions?

the IntentService source:

```
public class CheckerService extends IntentService {

private static final byte[] SALT = ....;
private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = ...;
private String device_id;

public CheckerService() {
    super("CheckerService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences("data", MODE_PRIVATE);
    device_id = data.getString("device_id", null);

    if (device_id == null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        device_id = new DeviceId().generate(this);
        editor.putString("device_id", device_id);
        editor.commit();
    }

    ServerManagedPolicy smp = new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
            new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), device_id));
    LicenseChecker checker = new LicenseChecker(this, smp, BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
    checker.checkAccess(new LicenseCheckerCallback(){

        public void allow() {
            Intent i = new Intent();                
            i.setAction("com.mainapp.intent.action.LICENSE_RESPONSE");
            i.putExtra("response", "LICENSE_OK");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        public void dontAllow() {
            Intent i = new Intent();                
            i.setAction("com.mainapp.intent.action.LICENSE_RESPONSE");
            i.putExtra("response", "LICENSE_NOT_OK");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }

        public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
            Intent i = new Intent();                
            i.setAction("com.mainapp.intent.action.LICENSE_RESPONSE");
            i.putExtra("response", "LICENSE_ERROR");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }});

}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    checker.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Were you able to do this? There needs to be more LVL examples

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem is with the IntentService. An IntentService manages it's own lifecycle. Essentially it is just a service that runs on a non-UI thread. The service is destroyed before the callback can be handled, so when the callback occurs nothing exists for it to 'callback' to.

You could try to run it in a service with START_STICKY or START_NOT_STICKY and manage the lifecycle yourself.